# How to check minimize or make if-condition on object loop more correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through an object and finding whether or not the object has the "key," along with some further stuff.

I feel that there is some other correct way to do this apart from this:

```
var initialLocalesGen = function(data){

    var status;


    if(!$.isEmptyObject(data)){

        console.log(data);

        if(data.hasOwnProperty("username") && data.hasOwnProperty("name")){ 
            var headerHtml = Handlebars.compile($("#header-template").html());
            $("#userInfoBar").append(headerHtml({"username" : data["username"], "name" : data["name"]}));
        }

        if(data.hasOwnProperty("allLocales")){
            var formHtml = Handlebars.compile($("#locale-template").html());
            $("form legend").after(formHtml(data["allLocales"])).end().find("span.submit").css({display:"block"});  
        }

        if(data.hasOwnProperty("status") && parseInt(data["status"]) === 0){
                currentStatus = 0;
                var object1 = {"status" : data["status"] , "userLocales": data["userLocales"]}
                userLocalesProcess(object1);    
        }

        if(data.hasOwnProperty("status") && parseInt(data["status"]) === 1){
                currentStatus = 1;      
                userChangeProcess({"changeLocales" : data["changeLocales"],"userLocales" : data["userLocales"] });
                popupMaker({"message":data["message"],"status":data["status"]});
        }

        if(data.hasOwnProperty("status") && parseInt(data["status"]) === 2){
                currentStatus = 2;          
        }

    }

    console.log("currentStatus:", currentStatus);

}
```

Could anyone help me minimize the condition or show me an even better way of doing it?

Comment: Why do your objects always have different attributes? What is `data`?

Comment: data is object which i am getting from Backend, it contains all sub datas(values)

Comment: Of course data is an object and has values ;) More details please.

Comment: Found a nice link for [checking properties in javascript](http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in-vs-other/4)

Comment: On a side-note, you should probably use either a switch  or else-ifs for the conditions if they are exclusive, if more than one will never be true. It will make the relationships between the statements more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the last three ifs. (I assume there are no other states.)

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty("status")){
        currentStatus =  parseInt(data["status"]);
        switch(currentStatus ) {
             case 0:
                  var object1 = {"status" : data["status"] , "userLocales": data["userLocales"]}
                  userLocalesProcess(object1);    
                  break;
             case 1:  
                  userChangeProcess({"changeLocales" : data["changeLocales"],"userLocales" : data["userLocales"] });
                  popupMaker({"message":data["message"],"status":data["status"]});
                  break;
             default:
                  break;
        }

}
```

I think there is nothing else you can do here. All other ifs are totally different. Maybe you could extract method or variables do communicate the meaning of every branch, but beside that I thing we are done.

---

Of course, if is also suitable

```
...
if (currentStatus ==0) {
    var object1 = {"status" : data["status"] , "userLocales": data["userLocales"]}
    userLocalesProcess(object1);    
} else if (currentStatus ==1){
    userChangeProcess({"changeLocales" : data["changeLocales"],"userLocales" : data["userLocales"] });
    popupMaker({"message":data["message"],"status":data["status"]});
}
...
```

---

Maybe you should just stay with `obj.property == null`. According to the [link above](http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in-vs-other/4) it seems to be faster, but at least it is easier to read.

Comment: But i red a article saying, we should try to avoid the switch cases..

Comment: Why? Link? You can do the same with an if.

Comment: should we use the if or else if?

Comment: Update my post. Still interested in the article!